# RC0 Denali - Cube Browser - Drag levels or measures here to add to the query..... - Where are the, "Drop Filter Fields here"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, ssas

Currently, working with RC0 Denali, having some issues I am attempting to review data in the cube browser and I am using the adventureworks tutorial as my guide.  Everything so far has been pretty cut and dry.  I am now at the point where I want to drop filter fields and drop column fields and drop row fields into the Data Pane.

I am currently working in visual studio 2010.  My data pane does not show any of the three above droppable areas that I described.  Nor does it show "drop totals or details fields here".  Mine shows "Drag levels or measures here to add to the query".

This page is a good example of what i am expecting to see. :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170646.aspx

I am wondering if I am either missing a setting or MSDN tutorials are incorrect as this is a rather new product.

Comment: The link for the 2012 documentation would be [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170646(v=SQL.110).aspx) but it has not been updated. You can still drag the row fields onto the canvas but I couldn't get it to take a column field. Filter field, can't you just use the upper sash and drop your dimension there?

Comment: Yes, I agree it hasn't been updated.  I could see that you could use the filter field in the top pane.  I was more or less getting at there seems to be a change between the old versions to the new (which isn't suprising), and wasn't sure if I was missing an option for the lower pane to show the previous versions settings or if someone knew how to produce the column/row results of previous versions on RC0.  Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [link](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/712042/ssas-2012-display-of-hierarchies), it appears this is an issue with the new control they are using...

> Hi, thanks for your feedback on the cube browser in SQL Server 2012. **We are aware that hierarchies that you defined in the model no longer show up in the cube browser. This is a limitation of the new control we are using.**
>
> Other customers have also asked for a better experience in the cube browser. We will consider enhancements in this area in a future release. I am resolving this issue as a duplicate of the customer bug (feedback ID 680476), feel free to vote it up and add your comments.
>
> Should you need this reply translated to Russian, send a line to nmed@microsoft.com and tell him I sent you.
>
> Regards,
> Cathy Dumas
> Program Manager, Analysis Services

Comment: Closest thing I have seen to answer regarding this, thanks for the info on this.